# Are there any tools to test and Deploy RAML 1.0?

Tags: api, mule, raml

I am working on a RAML project, to which i need to **test** & **Deploy** Raml files *locally*. So, Are there any **Raml Tester** tools available?
ps. i tried [**abao**](https://github.com/cybertk/abao), which is for 0.8 version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run and test RAML file by creating APIkit project using mule anypoint studio. Here is the link that explains process of creating APIKit project using RAML file and testing using APIkit console  https://docs.mulesoft.com/apikit/apikit-tutorial.

Once APIkit project is up and running anypoint studio, you can also use any REST test apps( http://raml.org/developers/test-your-api) such as Postman to send request and receive response instead of APIkit console.